# Помогите с Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Что не так с ним? Вот ошибка:

```
Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$id
```

Вот на что ругается:

```
public static function _getUserChanceOfGame($user, $game1x1)
{
    $chance = 0;
    if (!is_null($user)) {
        $bet = Bet_1x1::where('game_id', $game1x1->id)
            ->where('user_id', $user->id) // Ругается сюда
            ->sum('price');
            if ($bet == 0) {
                $chance = 0;
            } else {
                $chance = round($bet / $game1x1->price, 3) * 100;
            }
    }
    return $chance;
}
```

Если что-то ещё нужно скинуть, я скину.

Answer (score 1):

То, что $user не null еще не значит, что это объект.
Сделай прерывание и посмотри, что в $user

```
public static function _getUserChanceOfGame($user, $game1x1)
{
    $chance = 0;
    dump($user);
    if (!is_null($user)) {
        $bet = Bet_1x1::where('game_id', $game1x1->id)
            ->where('user_id', $user->id) // Ругается сюда
            ->sum('price');
            if ($bet == 0) {
                $chance = 0;
            } else {
                $chance = round($bet / $game1x1->price, 3) * 100;
            }
    }
    return $chance;
}
```

а что-бы работало, ставь проверку на объект как минимум

```
public static function _getUserChanceOfGame($user, $game1x1)
{
    $chance = 0;
    if (is_object($user) && property_exists($user,'id')) {
        $bet = Bet_1x1::where('game_id', $game1x1->id)
            ->where('user_id', $user->id) // Ругается сюда
            ->sum('price');
            if ($bet == 0) {
                $chance = 0;
            } else {
                $chance = round($bet / $game1x1->price, 3) * 100;
            }
    }
    return $chance;
}
```

Comment: Collection {#271 ▼
  #items: []
} Пишет

Comment: Пустая коллекция.
На входе ничего не приходит